# Is it possible to estimate the DOA from real samples only?

Tags: algorithms, array-signal-processing

I'm sampling a ULA with a scope after transmitting a CW.
I'm wondering if I can estimate the DOA assuming I'm interested only
in the range [0,90] [deg] and not the full [-90,90] [deg].
The first issue is how to correctly calibrate the different channels (different delay lines and gains) with real samples only.
the second issue is the question if an algorithm like MUSIC can handle real samples only.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by real samples? What do you measure? For a CW, the magnitude would be constant along the array since the information of the DOA is in the phase. Hence the magnitude doesn't help you. If you're measuring the real or imaginary part, it's a different story.

Comment: Thanks. I'm transmitting a cos(w*t) from Tx antenna to a reflector and then receive it by a of 4 Rx antennas ULA.  Then sampling directly (without demodulation) with a scope. Now, I thought of measuring the relative phase and gain between the channels at known doa angle = 0 as a calibration matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If you transmit $\cos(w t)$ and everything is assumed ideal, your antennas should receive something like $\cos(wt-\phi_i)$, where $\phi_i$ are phase shifts that are due to the different transmission delays between source and antenna ($\phi_i = w\tau_i$). Note that $$\cos(wt-\phi_i) = \frac 12 \left( {\rm e}^{\jmath (wt-\phi_i)} + {\rm e}^{-\jmath (wt-\phi_i)}\right).$$ Hence, if you feed your measured cosines into an algorithm like MUSIC, it will see two virtual sources with opposing signs in their delays. Otherwise it works perfectly. Just expect the number of sources to be twice as high.

If this disturbs you, one way to eliminate the mirror source is to apply Hilbert transform to your real-valued data (which complexifies it).

Comment: Thanks! I thought of down converting it to I and Q by multiply it by cos(wt)+jsin(wt) and then Low Pass filtering it. The next thing is to multiply it by the inverse of a calibration matrix which is the baseband samples of the known 4 channels samples at angle= 0 on the diagonal. I think it's something similar to your idea.

Comment: and then of course apply MUSIC.

Comment: Sure. What you're describing is a complex demodulation centered at $w$. This should filter out the mirror source just as well.